# How to increase the tap area of UIButton

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I am using the following code to resize the buttons in my appplication

```
+(void) processButton:(UIButton*) button buttonType:(NSString*)buttonType {
    ENDebug(@"Process button %@" ,[button restorationIdentifier]);
    [button setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:true];
    CGRect rect = [button frame];
    float startx = rect.origin.x;
    float midx = startx +rect.size.width/2;
    float starty = rect.origin.y;
    float midy = starty +rect.size.height/2;

    if ([buttonType isEqualToString:BUTTON_IPAD_SMALL]||[buttonType isEqualToString:BUTTON_IPHONE_SMALL]) {
        rect.size.width = BUTTON_WIDTH_SMALL;
        rect.size.height = BUTTON_HEIGHT_SMALL;
    } else {
        rect.size.width = BUTTON_WIDTH_LARGE;
        rect.size.height = BUTTON_HEIGHT_LARGE;
    }

    rect.origin.x = midx - rect.size.width/2;
    rect.origin.y = midy-rect.size.height/2;
    button.titleLabel.font = GillSansBold(BUTTON_TITLE_SIZE);
    [button setFrame:rect];
}
```

Using this I am able to resize the code.. but am not able to increase the tap size of the buttons.. Looks like only the view has expanded without the button becoming clickable in entirety.

Comment: On a different platform I addressed this problem by defining a second, larger, transparent button over the top of the first.

Comment: That should not happen. Increasing the button frame increases its tap area. Check if autolayout constraints are overriding your custom frame.

Answer (score 0):

Check the edge insets of the button. An inset is a margin around the drawing rectangle. Or you cant just try:

```
button.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

after setting the button's frame.